# Bring user back to app when Gmail back button is clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, gmail, back

I am navigating my app user to Gmail app when he clicks on a certain link inside my app. The redirection is working fine. But when the user hits the back button on the device or the toolbar of Gmail, he is redirected to Gmail inbox instead of getting the user back to my app.

I am doing something like so :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Is there a way the user can be taken back to my app instead of Gmail inbox when clicked on back button, or some other solution to achieve this functionality? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Old question but you need to open the Gmail app in new task. add this flag to your intent.
`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible as you redirect the user to the another app which is another scope. Handling of the back button should be Gmail App's business then.

I also would like to know if there is any way to do it.

```
String mailto = "mailto:mailaddress1@domain.com" +
                "?cc=" + "mailto:mailaddress2@domain.com" +
                "&subject=" + Uri.encode("subject") +
                "&body=" + Uri.encode("text is here");

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mailto));

try {
    startActivity(emailIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
    //TODO: Handle case where no email app is available
}
```

I have tried to send an e-mail using Gmail App. After sending an e-mail, I got back to my app but I have not found any way to implement an action for back button.

Comment: Yes. I wish there was a way to hold the context of the current app.

Comment: Thanks. It works for the send action but the back button still closes the gmail app and gets the user out of my app as well/